# Git merge different features that has been modified same files

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I am currently testing out using feature branches on my git flow.
Let say that I have a current stable script.

**current stable version for dog on dev branch**

```
    file 1
    ---------
    function bark() {
        return 'the dog is barking';
    }

    function walk() {
        return 'the dog is walking'
    }


    file 2
    ---------
    Action

    <button type="submit" name="button1">Play</button>

    <button type="submit" name="button2">Play</button>

    if($_POST["button1"]) {
        bark();
    }

    if($_POST["button2"]) {
        walk();
    }
```

then, Peter has been asked to add new feature `cat` as same as `current stable version for dog` . So, Peter do a clone `current stable version` to new feature branch called `features/cat`. Peter will modify all `current stable version` code.

**Peter cloning current stable version to Features/cat and already modified the current stable version**

```
    file 1
    -----------------------------
    function animalSound($animals = []) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($animals as $animal) {
            if($animal == 'cat') {
                $sound = 'meowing';
            } else if($animal == 'dog') {
                $sound = 'barking';
            }

            $result[] = 'The ' . $animal . ' is ' . $sound. 
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function animalWalk($animals = []) {
        $result = [];

        foreach($animals as $animal) {
            $result[] = 'The ' . $animal . ' is walking';
        }
    }


    file 2
    ---------
    Action

    <button type="submit" name="button1">Play</button>

    <button type="submit" name="button2">Play</button>

    if($_POST["button1"]) {
        bark(['dog', 'cat']);
    }

    if($_POST["button2"]) {
        walk(['dog', 'cat']);
    }
```

We assume that Peter has not completely built the script and now I asked Susan to build `run` feature for `current stable version` for dog.
Then Susan do clone `current stable version` to new feature branch called `features/dogrun`

**Susan: Features/dogrun**

```
    file 1
    ----------------
    function bark() {
        return 'the dog is barking';
    }

    function walk() {
        return 'the dog is walking'
    }

    // add run feature
    function run() {
        return 'the dog is running';
    }

    file 2
    ---------
    Action

    <button type="submit" name="button1">Play</button>

    <button type="submit" name="button2">Play</button>

    // menambah fitur run
    <button type="submit" name="button3">Play</button>

    if($_POST["button1"]) {
        bark();
    }

    if($_POST["button2"]) {
        walk();
    }

    // add run feature
    if($_POST["button3"]) {
        run();
    }
```

Let say that Susan has already finished built the `run feature` and that feature is already in production.
Now `Peter: features/cat` is already in staging branch and ready for production. how to merge `Peter: features/cat` and `Susan: features/run`? from between features all the code has changed and cannot be merged. if `Peter: features/cat` merge to master branch(production) first, `Susan: features/run` will not working anymore.

**This example case is only simple script, Because in my real case there's a lot many same files would be modified by another and the codes would be more complex.**

Comment: welcome to the world of development. Rule # 1: **conflicts are a part of life, be ready to deal with them**. Joke aside, don't just think in terms of "lines of code/files" (which is fine for what git does, but you are in control of git when doing stuff, so it's about what you should think of). Consider the _intent_ of each branch. So, each branch we could assume the work to be correct and their intent requires changes on the files. So, if they have to be modified in different ways, in order to get them together.. well, you have to find a way to do it. Git does the best it can: report conflicts

Answer (score 1):

You should not merge those branches if they involve conflicts.

Peter should, when ready, *rebase* his features/cat on top of the latest `master` production branch, in order to replay locally (on his workstation) his `features/cat` commits.

Conflicts will arise there (in Peter's environment), and resolved there (by Peter)

A subsequent merge to `master` will then be trivial.

Comment: so does it mean that peter should responsible for the `dogrun feature`?

Comment: I don't mean to merge the both features branch, but i don't know how to handle if the cases are like that..  because  they will replace each other scripts when commit to master. if 2 feature branches have some same files, and they both modified same lines in same files, there would be so many conflict and must rebuild the script  to combine those feature.

Comment: @BabaCarita No, Peter is responsible for making his own code run on top of whatever is currently in production. Hence the rebase, which replays *his* commits.

Comment: so if Peter rebase `features/cat` then how about `features/dogrun` that has already in master branch?

Comment: @BabaCarita by rebasing `features/cat` on top of master, Peter will resolve any conflict. Since master already includes `features/dogrun`, Peter will have to deal with concurrent development done on a common file.

Comment: @BabaCarita It will be Peter's responsibility to make his feature works with `features/dogrun` already in master. If that is too complex, then it is to the project leader to adequately decoupled those functions, in order for them to be developed separately if needed. Or, alternatively, the project leader can decide from now on for only one feature branch for those type of developments. In any case, it is an project organization and communication issue. Not so much a version control tool issue.

Comment: It will be Peter's responsibility to make his feature works with features/dogrun already in master. => that's why this kind of work will make it complicated. This example case is only simple script, Because in my real case there's a lot many same files would be modified by another and the codes would be more complex. so it could not be a peter responsible to build the `features/dogrun` again while the feature was already on master branch.

Comment: Or, alternatively, the project leader can decide from now on for only one feature branch for those type of developments. In any case, it is an project organization and communication issue. Not so much a version control tool issue = I will accept this suggestion in mind..

Comment: @BabaCarita Yes, the idea of my answer is to point out the normal workflow (rebase, local resolution of any conflict). If that is not convenient, that illustrates more a project organization issue, not so much a version control issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195676/discussion-between-baba-carita-and-vonc).